# Registration Page not Saving Data to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Am having trouble saving data into my db after inserting it from my registration form.

Funny enough, only two fields are being saved. i.e., The First and Last Name, but things such as Phone number aren't no matter how hard I try to look for the solution.

Below are the files used to connect the Mysql Db with the Registration Form.

**1. REGISTRATION.PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h3 {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 22pt;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: SlateBlue;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: underline
        }
        table {
            font-family: Calibri;
            color: white;
            font-size: 11pt;
            font-style: normal;
            text-align:;
            background-color: SlateBlue;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px solid navy
        }
        table.inner {
            border: 0px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="check.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="300" border="0"
    <table align="center" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td>FirstName:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LastName:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="LastName"></td>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td><input type="double" name="Phone"></td>
        </tr>
        <span style="size:10%;color:#FF0000"><?php if(isset($_GET["pass"])) { echo $_GET["pass"]; } ?></span>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="registration"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. CHECK.PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['registration'])) {
    require "connection.php";
    $FirstName = strip_tags($_POST['FirstName']);
    $LastName  = strip_tags($_POST['LastName']);
    $DOB       = strip_tags($POST['Phone']);

    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO users
            (FirstName, LastName, Phone)
        VALUES
            ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Phone')
    ") or die("" . mysql_error());
    echo "Successful Registration!";
}
?>
```

**3. CONNECTION.PHP**

```
<?
$name   = "root";
$pas    = "password";
$dbname = "registration";
$con    = mysql_connect("localhost:7077", $name, $pas);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
?>
```

Comment: I can see that your $Phone variable just doesn't exist. You strip the tags around it and store it in the $DOB variable, but later in the query, you reference a $Phone variable.

Comment: You have `$DOB = $POST['Phone'];`. You are probably looking for `$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];`.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right. `strip_tags` is nowhere even *close* to doing it correctly.

Comment: @DanielStutz, have made ammendments to the code but still the same thing happens.

Comment: @tadman, looking into that, as am so green in coding, only a month old

Comment: It's great to hear you're learning. Step one in your journey is: Never, ever use `mysql_query`. It's an artifact from the 1990s that, unfortunately, is promoted in way too many tutorials. If you want to become an effective developer, your time will be better spent learning a [popular framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) because you'll be able get more done in less time, and you won't have to fuss with really low-level concerns like this nearly as often. Slapping together pages with a mess of SQL, PHP, HTML and JavaScript is not sustainable.

Comment: @larrylampco, Thank You for noticing that, had totally missed it due to fatigue.

Comment: @KnightSlayer did you try to ECHO the query to see how the values are set in the query ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$DOB = strip_tags($POST['Phone']);
```

This should be replaced with

```
$Phone = strip_tags($_POST['Phone']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I didn't exactly understand what you wanted to do here:

```
<table width="300" border="0"<table align="center" cellpadding = "10">
```

But that won't solve your problem. Can you show us the types of your db cells? Maybe you just have a wrong cell declaration. They should be int, tinytext or varchar.

Comment: 1  ID  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change
 2  Phone  double   NULL   Change Change

Comment: Hope it helps... But the solution above of
 

$DOB = strip_tags($POST['Phone']);

This should be replaced with

$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];

Did it for me, Thank You All The Same!